# Create nginx server in Google Cloud Platform Cloud Shell

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform

I am starting working with Google Cloud Platform and, as my first try, I have installed and configured an nginx server in the Cloud Shell (not Compute Engine Virtual Machine)

When I try a:

> curl http://127.0.0.1:8080

I get a:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused

My question is: does it make no sense running in a **web server in Cloud Shell in the Dashboard** (IMPORTANT: I am not trying a new Compute Engine Virtual Machine) or I it is possible and it is just me not configuring nginx correctly? (I just added a status.conf file with minimum information, that would work straight away in my Linux)

Comment: What you ask makes *no* sense. The cloud shell is not a VM, is not intended as one, and probably doesn't include this functionality. It's meant to interface the services offered by Google Cloud.

Comment: Where are you running the `curl` command? The IP address `127.0.0.1` is only accessible from inside Cloud Shell and not from a system on the Internet.

Comment: @JohnHanley Everything on Cloud Shell, curl included

Comment: Is Nginx running? Show the Nginx configuration in your post. Typically, Nginx is configured for port 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not generally common to use Cloud shell for what you are trying to do, there is nothing stopping you from running nginx and accessing it from within Cloud Shell.

Once you install nginx, make sure it is running and note the port. Nginx by default uses port 80, so try to curl on that port.

This is the output from my cloud shell -

```
$ sudo service nginx start

$ sudo netstat -eplant |grep nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          34868      2996/nginx: master  
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          34869      2996/nginx: master  


$ curl -I localhost
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.18.0
```